# Removing padding on last-child results in different sized element

Tags: css, css-selectors, grid, padding

I have an image gallery with horizontal thumbnails below the featured image. I am adding `padding-right:10px;` to all but the last-child in an effort to equally space these elements. This works as intended on all but the last thumbnail, where it's slightly larger than the rest.

It makes sense why this is happening, but I am not sure how to fix it. This was the solution recommended on numerous other Stack Overflow posts. Any workaround would be appreciated.

[image]

```
<style>
.gallery-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 30px;
}
.image-thumb {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding-right: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.image-thumb:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}
</style>

    <div class="gallery-grid">

            <img id="featured-image" src="featured.jpg" style="width:100%">

            <div class="image-thumb">
                <img src="featured_thumb.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
            </div>
            <div class="image-thumb">
                <img src="thumb.jpg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
            </div>
            <div class="image-thumb">
                <img src="thumb.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
            </div>
            <div class="image-thumb">
                <img src="thumb.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
            </div>
            <div class="image-thumb">
                <img src="thumb.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
            </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick using `float` insteed of `flex` you could use `margin` insteed of `padding`. Then you can calculate the total space taken by the margin, divide it between the number of elements and rest it to the width using `calc`

`(margin-right:10px * 4) / 5 = 8`

Example:

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
.box {
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
  float:left;
  width:calc(20% - 8px);
  margin-right:10px;
}
.box:nth-child(5) {margin-right:0;}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Would flex be a better option instead of float?

Comment: Up to you. I'm "old school" and I still use float most of the time as I feel (just a feeling) than I have more control over the layout, specially at responsive... But many will disagree with me.

Comment: My solution have some cons... often you wont' find the division between elements an exact number of pixels (for example... 4 elements insteed of 5, will give you 7.5px... in those moments I change the margin-right to 12px. nobody will notice the difference but you)